# Determine the orthogonal trajectory of the curves

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've gotten stuck on the following problem:

> Determine the orthogonal trajectories to the family of curves $$(x-c)^2 + (y-c)^2 = 2c^2$$

Here's what I've done so far.  You can solve for $c$ as $\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2x + 2y}$.  Then $$2(x-c) + 2(y-c)y' = 0$$ so $$y' = - \frac{x-c}{y-c} = - \frac{x - \frac{x^2+y^2}{2x+2y}}{y - \frac{x^2+y^2}{2x+2y}} = -\frac{x^2 +2xy - y^2}{y^2 + 2xy - x^2}$$ The orthogonal trajectories are the solutions to the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^2 + 2xy - x^2}{x^2 + 2xy - y^2}$$ which I'm now having trouble solving.  I tried (going along with the example in the textbook I'm using) the substitution $V = \frac{y}{x}$, but it quickly appears to be more trouble than it's worth.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The easiest way out is $V = y/x$.

Comment: Is it necessary to eliminate the parameter $c$? Life is much easier if you just solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-c}{x-c}$ for the orthogonal trajectories.

Comment: I wonder if it would be easier just to rotate the axes by $45^\circ$?